# Can someone tell me whats wrong on this 4 bit counting circuit?

Tags: counter

The circuits are a 555 timer and a 74161 counter, its supposed to do a simple 4 bit count up, however when I give it 5V it just keeps the first LED permanently on without changing[image]

And the schematic 
[image]

Comment: Step 0: Post a schematic. Notice that this is not even step 1. This is something which should be given.

Comment: Does the 555 oscillate? Add a resistor and a LED in series to its output (pin 3) and see if it blinks.

Comment: And please add a more descriptive subject line.  Your subject line is making everyone who makes circuits click on your item.  Maybe something as simple as '555 timer and counter circuit not working'

Comment: Thanks will change the title and make the schematic (i dont have one this is why i hadnt posted it)and yes the 555 oscillate with a periodo of little more than a second

Comment: Schematic added!

Comment: Geez, ya could've at least put some reference designators on it and   rotate it to save us the grief...

Comment: Check the power supply rails of the counter (pin 1 and 14), maybe add a decoupling cap, check all the control pins of the counter are high (to be sure of loose connection). Check that the clock signal is there - put an LED on the clock line to see if it is blinking. If all else fails, try a new counter IC.

Comment: There is a built in schematic tool in the post editor. It will help you create clear (and right-side-up) schematics.

Comment: Is is appearently current , because i just plugged it in a pc power supply and it works!!! However un the cellphone power supply it doesnt, any idea why? Also should i close this post and open a new one if now the problem is when adding a second counter?

Comment: It's a different question, so yes, post it as a new question and **please** use a schematic editor; either the built-in one or one of your own choice. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with, although your 555 oscillates, your timing cap is too large and the resistors too small.  10uF, 100k, and 1k would be better, and 1uF, 1 meg, and 10k would be even better.

Also, get rid of the 10uF (or use it for the timing cap) and put 100nF directly across pins 1 and 8.

As far as the counter goes, if you're getting a clock into it and all the other pins are at the right voltages and the Q's won't toggle, I'd suspect a bad chip.

That LED connected to the MSB looks like it's been rode hard and put up wet, so it may be that at one time the counter was hooked up to, say, 12V by mistake and  POOF! out came the magic smoke?

Finally, it's not a good idea to source current from LSTTL into LEDs, since LSTTL is only specified to source 400uA or so, which won't make your 20mA LEDs light up very brightly.